# Is there a way to automate the process of creating sessions and panes in tmux

Tags: tmux

I have huge list of programs to run in tmux session
is there any simple way so that we give session name and specify which pane runs which program.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can either do this with tmux commands in a shell script, for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

S=$(tmux new -dP -smysession 'myprogram1')
W=$(tmux neww -dP -t$S 'myprogram2')
tmux -t$W splitw 'myprogram3'
```

Or a tmux script you can load with `tmux source-file` or from `.tmux.conf`:

```
new -smysession 'myprogram1'
neww 'myprogram2'
splitw 'myprogram3'
```

Or you could look at the many existing wrapper programs to do this. The most popular are:

- https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator
- https://github.com/tmux-python/tmuxp
- https://github.com/remiprev/teamocil

There is a list at https://github.com/rothgar/awesome-tmux#tools-and-session-management.